# Vue-router errors, javascript undefined properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I have a function to get the logged in user details and check for the '**permissions**' in the '**teams array**'.

However, after running the code, I got two errors, and after the UI is loaded, the currentUser displays null until any component in the UI is selected. See the image, currentUser is null when UI is loaded but as soon as I click on a component, it prints the currentUser. I do not understand how to get through these errors.

This is a part of the vue-store code from which I am getting the currentUser array:

```
state(){
 return currentUser: null
}
mutations: {
   setCurrentUser(state, payload) {
      // console.log("set current user", payload);
      state.currentUser = payload;
    }
  },
actions: {
    loadCurrentUser(context, data) {
      // console.log("loadcurrentuser");
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axiosService({ requiresAuth: true })
          .get(`/administration/users/${data.id}`)
          .then(response => {
            context.commit("setCurrentUser", response.data);
            resolve(response.data);
          })
          .catch(error => reject(error));
      });
    },
}
getters: {
    isCurrentUser(state){
      return state.currentUser;
    }
  }
```

here is the code from the router.js

```
{
  path: "/administration",
    name: "Administration",
    component: PageAdministration,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
      neededPermissions: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
   },

function authorizeUser(to, from,next) {
  let isAllowed = true;
  const currentUser = store.getters["auth/isCurrentUser"];
  console.log(currentUser);

  for(let i = 0;i<currentUser.teams.length;i++){
    const team = currentUser.teams[i]
    const validPermissions = team.permissions.filter((item) => { return to.meta.neededPermissions.includes(item.permissionType); }); //returns array of objects
    const mappedValidPermissions = validPermissions.map((item) => { return item.permissionType;  });// returns array with permissionType
    if (!to.meta.neededPermissions.every(i=>mappedValidPermissions.includes(i))) {
      isAllowed = false;
      next({ path: "/:notFound(.*)" });    

      break;
    } 
  }

  if(isAllowed) next();
}


router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  
  if (to.meta.requiresAuth && !store.getters["auth/isLoggedIn"]) {
    next({
      name: "Authentication",
      params: {
        desiredRoute: to.fullPath,
      },
    });
  } else {
    authorizeUser(to,next)
  }
});
```

These are the two errors
[image: errors]

Comment: You can't read properties of objects that are null.  so when `currentUser` is null, `currentUser.teams` is the same as `null.teams` which causes an error because teams isn't a property of null (nothing is!).  it's not clear how/when currentUser is populated but generally you should add checks (e.g. `if` statements) that check if an object like currentUser is null before trying to use it.

Comment: Then how can I get the currentUser data to verify the permissions?

Comment: If you're making an async call to load currentUser then you need to wait for the async call to finish before you check for permissions.  Async calls take some amount of time (even if only a very short amount of time), while a lot of code executes near instantly (your authorizeUser code).  You have to take care that your code runs in the correct order